# Unity shader to turn top-down view of scene into a stylized "minimap" view?

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm working on a **tile based** isometric game and the **minimap** right now is just a **top-down camera**.

Usually I just attach some markers to the top of the objects in the world, which are only visible by the minimap camera.

But I want a better approach than this, so some kind of a **stylized shader**.

I guess I have to **render only the floors** in this camera... and then I'm stuck.

How could I **turn the "real, ingame view of the floors"** into some "**stylzed/procedural textured"** versions like the examples below?

Thanks in advance!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to change about the appearance of your current output? Your map seems to be very different from the example image, so it's not immediately obvious which elements of that source you want to incorporate.

Comment: Do you need help with creating the shader? Or do you need help with how to get the minimap camera and the main view camera to render the same objects with different shaders?

Comment: I need help with the shader. The images in the posts are only examples. My minimap looks as it should be looking for a camera looking at the scene from above. And I want a similar shading like in the examples above.

Comment: The trouble is that the two examples above use very *different* shading, so it's not clear to a reader what kind of answer would best fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your project uses the standard render pipeline, then you can use a script on the minimap camera which [sets a replacement shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderReplacement.html). But you would still render the whole scene twice, which could in the worst-case scenario cost you half of your FPS.

A better solution would be to have two completely separate visual representations for each object which is supposed to show up on the minimap.

1. Create a new [layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) called "MinimapObject"
2. Configure the culling mask of your main camera to render everything **except** the "MinimapObject" layer
3. Configure the culling mask of your minimap camera to render **only** the "MinimapObject" layer
4. Attach a child-object to every game object which is supposed to show up on the minimap.
5. Set the layer of those child-objects to "MinimapObject"
6. Create the visual representation on the minimap in the "MinimapObject" child. In the case of level geometry, that would mean a lower detail version of the regular mesh with your stylized shader material. You could also represent points of interest (like quest objectives, for example) as sprites or add text labels to your minimap as world-space canvases.

Comment: [Unity does provide a way to re-render the scene from a different view with selected shaders replaced by other shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderReplacement.html), but I agree it's not exactly "straight-forward".

Comment: @DMGregory Interesting. I didn't know about that. I guess I can still learn something new about Unity from you every day. I still don't think it's a good idea in this particular case, but I am going to mention it nevertheless.

Comment: You don't need to render the whole scene twice if you're using the Culling Mask on your minimap camera. Additionally, it looks like the replacement shader would not need to consider lighting, which reduces the render complexity.